# Going fullscreen with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have a web page where I want to let the user to click a button and start to watch a video in fullscreen mode. However, I don't want the video to play immediately after clicking the button. I want it to wait some seconds and then play the video and go fullscreen. To achieve this; I have used the setTimeout function like so;

```
 function startVideoAfterSecs(seconds){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activateFullscreen(); // function to go fullsreen
      this.player.play();
    }, seconds);
  };
```

I know that it is not possible to go fullscreen without a user interaction, there should be some user event to trigger it. That's why, `startVideoAfterSecs` is bound to a button's `onclick` event. However, I am still getting the error;

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fullscreen error

I know that this error is causing about a browser blockage, because it does not accept it as a user action since the `setTimeout` function is being used. Are there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "`startVideoAfterSecs` is bound to a button's `onclick` event"

But `this.activateFullscreen()` and `this.player.play()` are not anymore, since they are called from the timeout callback.
But actually that's not even the problem, which is more that after some time the browsers will not consider the call as still being from a *user-interaction*, it seems to be around 5s in Chrome, but it may very well change at any time.

For the `play()` call, you can workaround that by calling it in the click event handler directly, then pausing as soon as possible. This will mark the HTMLMediaElement as user-activated, and you'll be able to call play on it whenever you want.

For the fullscreen mode though, no other way than requesting an other user's interaction, or to make it in that given time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the perfect explanation. After I saw your answer, I changed the timeout to 2, previously it was 5. It seems that, with using 2 seconds delay, I am not getting any error that I was getting with 5 seconds. But as you said, it looks like an unreliable way.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not tied by specs that they should keep it active for 5 seconds. But they do it for years now, so I guess it's *quite* safe.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure `this` is pointing to the element you want to go fullscreen. Also, try using `requestFullscreen()` instead. Here's an example of it working with setTimeout()...

https://jsfiddle.net/8u3t5ae7/